# How can I find all ASP.NET endpoints that could be affected by a code change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, static-analysis

I'm currently working on a large messy codebase that is not unit tested very well, and I have had to make a small change to a method that will potentially impact a number of API endpoints.

I've done some analysis using Find References in Rider and Call Hierarchy in Visual Studio (shame this doesn't exist in Rider yet), but I'm not entirely sure whether I've caught them all.

We will soon be re-writing the code, so bringing the entire codebase under proper code coverage isn't really a pragmatic solution.

Are there any other techniques / code analysis tools that I can use that will help me identify those endpoints that I need to target for manual Q.A.?

Comment: By designing and running integration tests (not unit-tests).

Comment: And write unit tests for the methods you are re-writing _before_ you rewrite them

Comment: Like I said I'm not rewriting anything yet, and I don't have time to completely cover the entire solution, so unfortunately those suggestions don't really help much. 

With regards to the future the new code will be built using characterisation tests based off the old codebase, but we intend to cover what we can with unit tests and integration test the things that lie on integration boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Righ-click changed method name, then select "Inspect", then select "Show incoming calls...". In the Inspection Results pane keep clicking "Expand All" button until it does stop expanding (have reached outer limis)